# just showing months on date picker

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have condition that when I put some value, the jqueryui datepicker shows days and when I put another value, the datepicker just shows months

```
function setdate(q){
            var d=new Date();
            if (q==1){
                var type={ 
                        0:"dd-mm-yyyy",
                        1:"days", 
                };
                d.setDate(d.getDate()-15);
            }
            else if (q==2){
                var type={ 
                        0:"mm-yyyy",
                        1:"months", 
                };
                d.setDate(d.getDate()-30);  
            }
            viewdate(d,type);
         }

         function viewdate(d,type){
            $('#from').datepicker({
                        format: type[0],
                        startView:type[1], 
                        minViewMode: type[1]
                    });
            $('#from').datepicker( 'setDate',d);
            $('#till').datepicker({
                        format: type[0],
                        startView:type[1], 
                        minViewMode: type[1]
                    });
            $('#till').datepicker( 'setDate', new Date());

         }
```

But when I put the months value, the datepicker is still showing days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is not called `format` but `dateFormat` (see the [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)):

```
$('#from').datepicker({
    dateFormat: type[0],
    ...
```

Second if the `datepicker` was already initialized you need to add the `option` parameter, else the call has no effect.

```
$('#from').datepicker('option', {
    dateFormat: type[0],
    ...
```

Also note that in the format string `yy` is used to display a four digit year (`yyyy` would display the year twice).

Comment: hhmmm, still not working. instead the date format is changing become dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: @sidzaky see my edit, probably you need to add the `option` parameter

Comment: same like my first comment.

Comment: :UPDATE after couple hours of coding i figure out that the datepicker i'm using is old version. and after i use you'r coding it works. sorry for confusing you @wero